# Unable to obtain kubeconfig of an AWS EKS cluster in Go code

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, aws-sdk-go

I have created an AWS EKS cluster. In order to obtain its kubeconfig, I usually run `aws eks update-kubeconfig --name cluster-name --region us-west-2` using a shell.

However, I now wish to obtain the kubeconfig in Go without having to run anything in the shell (the goal being to create and then manipulate an EKS cluster in a Go test). I am able to describe an EKS cluster using this code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/eks"
)

func main() {
    sess := session.Must(session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
        Region: aws.String("us-west-2"),
    }))
    eksSvc := eks.New(sess, aws.NewConfig().WithRegion("us-west-2"))


    clusterOutput, err := eksSvc.DescribeCluster(&eks.DescribeClusterInput{
        Name: aws.String("cluster-name"),
    })
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", clusterOutput)
}
```

After that, I currently have no idea about how could I get the kubeconfig of that cluster in order to then use it with the Go client for Kubernetes without having to use `aws eks` separately.

I have checked the AWS documentation, AWS CLI codebase, and `eksctl` codebase with no luck so far. The connection to an EKS cluster is only documented in this webpage and it uses a shell: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-cluster-connection/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The general flow goes something like this:

1. DescribeCluster (as you have done) and extract some necessary data
2. Using the necessary data, get a token using [aws-iam-authenticator](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-iam-authenticator)'s `package token`
3. Using that token, create a Kubernetes clientset with the help of [client-go](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go).

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/base64"
    "log"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/eks"
    metav1 "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"
    "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes"
    "k8s.io/client-go/rest"

    "sigs.k8s.io/aws-iam-authenticator/pkg/token"
)

func newClientset(cluster *eks.Cluster) (*kubernetes.Clientset, error) {
    log.Printf("%+v", cluster)
    gen, err := token.NewGenerator(true, false)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    opts := &token.GetTokenOptions{
        ClusterID: aws.StringValue(cluster.Name),
    }
    tok, err := gen.GetWithOptions(opts)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    ca, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(aws.StringValue(cluster.CertificateAuthority.Data))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    clientset, err := kubernetes.NewForConfig(
        &rest.Config{
            Host:        aws.StringValue(cluster.Endpoint),
            BearerToken: tok.Token,
            TLSClientConfig: rest.TLSClientConfig{
                CAData: ca,
            },
        },
    )
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return clientset, nil
}

func main() {
    name := "wonderful-outfit-1583362361"
    region := "us-east-2"
    sess := session.Must(session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
        Region: aws.String(region),
    }))
    eksSvc := eks.New(sess)

    input := &eks.DescribeClusterInput{
        Name: aws.String(name),
    }
    result, err := eksSvc.DescribeCluster(input)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error calling DescribeCluster: %v", err)
    }
    clientset, err := newClientset(result.Cluster)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error creating clientset: %v", err)
    }
    nodes, err := clientset.CoreV1().Nodes().List(metav1.ListOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error getting EKS nodes: %v", err)
    }
    log.Printf("There are %d nodes associated with cluster %s", len(nodes.Items), name)
}
```

Here's my go.mod for versions:

```
module github.com/swoldemi/sandbox

go 1.14

require (
    github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go v1.29.19
    k8s.io/apimachinery v0.0.0-20190612125636-6a5db36e93ad
    k8s.io/client-go v0.0.0-20190425172711-65184652c889
    sigs.k8s.io/aws-iam-authenticator v0.5.0
)
```

Comment: Great answer! You may also want to pass the session in the `GetTokenOptions` struct. See my answer.

Comment: @AndrésMejía and @Simon Is there a way to pass on access_key_id and secret_access_key to the `session.NewSession()` instead of having a requirement of looking into aws.config file or any other file.

Comment: @SuryavanshiVirendrasingh Yes, it's possible! You can just export the 2 keys to your environment and NewSession will find them from the environment using the default order of precedence 

* Access Key ID: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID or AWS_ACCESS_KEY

* Secret Access Key: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY or AWS_SECRET_KEY

Comment: @Simon Can you please elaborate on what do you mean by exporting the 2 keys to the environment?

Comment: @SuryavanshiVirendrasingh Assuming you're running your program in a shell: `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=access_key_id AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=secret_access_key go run youprogram.go`

See "How to set environment variables" on this page:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html

Comment: @Simon Ohh, I see what you meant by exporting the keys to the environment. But I don't want to do that as this will run in multiple environments and I don't think it will be a good practice to export it every time into different environments. So, is it possible to pass on directly the credentials to session.NewSession(), which I am receiving through Kafka stream through another service.

Comment: @SuryavanshiVirendrasingh I don't recommend that you try and pass credentials across a network, between services, from a location that isn't STS/IAM, but here's a snippet on how to create your own provider using credentials.Value and create a session suing those keys: https://play.golang.org/p/kmbVrBE_UT7

Comment: @SuryavanshiVirendrasingh sess, err := session.NewSessionWithOptions(session.Options{
  Config: aws.Config{
   Credentials: credentials.NewStaticCredentials(accessKey, secretKey, ""),
  }},
 )

Comment: wait..does nodes in the above code return kube config similar to the command line version aws update-kubeconfig?

Answer (score 8):

Adding to [Simon's great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60573982/137601), you may want to also pass the session in the `GetTokenOptions` struct, like so:

```golang
opts := &token.GetTokenOptions{
        ClusterID: aws.StringValue(cluster.Name),
        Session: sess,
    }
    tok, err := gen.GetWithOptions(opts)
```

Otherwise the `gen.GetWithOptions(opts)` call will try to read your AWS credentials from local sources (e.g. `~/.aws/credentials`) and may fail with this error:

```
NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.
    For verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors
```