# How to use kubernetes go-client on amazon eks service?

Tags: go, kubernetes, amazon-eks, client-go

I've been looking for documentation for a long time and still couldn't find any clear connection procedure.
I came up with this code sample :

```
package aws

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/eks"
    "github.com/joho/godotenv"
)
func Connect() {
    godotenv.Load(".env")
    session := session.Must(session.NewSession())
    svc := eks.New(session)
    clusters, err := svc.ListClusters(&eks.ListClustersInput{})
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Println(clusters)
}
```

i mean, this still returns a 403 forbidden error because of env variable mess, but the code is valid i guess. My question is, having this connection established : how to convert this `svc` variable into the `*kubernetes.Clientset` one from the go driver ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you had a look at the [client-go example](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/master/examples/in-cluster-client-configuration/main.go) on how to authenticate in-cluster?

Code that authenticate to the Kubernetes API typically start like this:

```
    // creates the in-cluster config
    config, err := rest.InClusterConfig()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    // creates the clientset
    clientset, err := kubernetes.NewForConfig(config)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
```

Comment: Does the in-cluster part mean that the controller app will have to be hosted inside the cluster I'm trying to connect to ?  Can't i connect from an external controller ?

Comment: You can see an out-of-cluster authentication here: https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/master/examples/out-of-cluster-client-configuration/main.go#L44-L62

Comment: Right, saw this right after posting ^^' Thanks for your time mate

Comment: Actually i still get the 403 unauthorized error. And that's pretty logical knowing that i didn't enter my access keys anywhere, and that the ~/.kube/config doesn't contain them either. Do you know where i might be able to set them up ?

Comment: If you try locally, you must first authenticate so that you can use kubectl against your cluster. The code is using the same credentials.

Comment: @rrrrr you need to generate acccess keys first and configure your aws cli and then you need to run the following command to generate ~/.kube/config
aws eks --region <region-code> update-kubeconfig --name <cluster_name>
you can refer this link for more information
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/create-kubeconfig.html

Comment: Yeah actually it was just because i kept loading an old .env file with wrong credentials ^^'

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code to automatically detect where its running from local machine or any kubernetes cluster.

```golang
var config *rest.Config
    if _, err := os.Stat("/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token"); err == nil {
        config, err = rest.InClusterConfig()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    } else if os.IsNotExist(err) {
        config, err = clientcmd.BuildConfigFromFlags("", *kubeConfig)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("No serviceaccount mounted or -kubeconfig flag passed or .kube/config file \n " ,err)
        }
    }
    // Create an rest client not targeting specific API version
    clientSet, err := kubernetes.NewForConfig(config)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60547409/unable-to-obtain-kubeconfig-of-an-aws-eks-cluster-in-go-code) will be useful if you had a workflow to get kubeconfig from ***aws eks update-kubeconfig cluster_name --kubeconfig=/my/path/file*** and then pass the kubeconfig to ***kubectl --kubeconfig=/my/path/file***  and now want to do the same using aws sdk and go k8s client library.